# After NAT how to setup VPN in windows server 2008 r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, vpn, nat, rras

We have one windows server 2008 R2 with about 10 Hyper-V virtual machines. We've used wizard that comes when you enable RRAS to setup NAT, so that virtual machines can connect to internet (and to access thoes VMs from outside via RDP).

Now we would like to use the same server as a VPN server as well. It is easy to setup the VPN when you go through the wizard that we've used to setup NAT, but now once we've used that wizard for setup of the NAT it is no longer available (at least not from RRAS application menu/tree view).

Is there somwhere some hidden point that starts whis VPN wizard? If not, then how to setup the VPN on the server that is also used as a NAT server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem, but in reverse: I had VPN set up but wanted to enable NAT.

To re-enable the wizard, open Routing and Remote Access, rightclick the server and choose Disable. I think this then re-enables the "Configure and Enable" option, which will re-run the wizard. It ended up refreshing my VPN settings, but these were just standard PPTP, so not much lost.

Good luck!